# Django queryset filtering and annotate

Tags: django, django-models

How to write in Django query that? Maybe in subquery? Someone can help?
I write in sql something like that:

```
select distinct tt.client_id
from
(select tk.client_id, min(tk.changedon) min_date
from app_tickets_ticket tk
where tk.status_id=7 and tk.active=FALSE
group by tk.client_id) tt, app_tickets_ticket tr
where
tr.client_id=tt.client_id
and tr.status_id in(5,6) and tr.active=FALSE
and tt.min_date::DATE between '2018-01-05'::DATE and '2018-12-09'::DATE
and tr.changedon::DATE<=tt.min_date::DATE
and tt.client_id not in(select tm.client_id from app_tickets_ticket tm
                   where tm.active=FALSE and tm.changedon::DATE between '2018-01-05'::DATE and '2018-12-09'::DATE
                     and tm.changedon<=tt.min_date
                   and tm.status_id in(8,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17))
union
select distinct tt.client_id from (
select tk.client_id, min(tk.changedon) min_date
from app_tickets_ticket tk
where tk.active=FALSE
group by tk.client_id
) tt, app_tickets_ticket tr
where tt.min_date::DATE between '2018-01-05'::DATE and '2018-12-09'::DATE
and tt.client_id=tr.client_id and tt.min_date=tr.changedon
and tr.status_id=7
```

TicketStatus model:

```
class TicketStatus(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=300, blank=False, null=False, default='-')
```

Clients model:

```
class Clients(models.Model):
     fio = models.CharField('Fio', max_length=300, blank=False, null=False)
```

Ticket model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(TicketStatus, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    createdon = models.DateTimeField('DateIn', auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    changedon = models.DateTimeField('DateOut', auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField('Active', default=True, blank=False, null=False)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Clients, verbose_name='Client', related_name='tickets', blank=True, null=True,
                           on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: Please share your models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't!

If your query is already tested and optimized, unless you want to do this an exercise in learning the Django ORM, it's way to much work to rewrite (and re-optimize) it.

You can execute SQL in Django, and with `raw`, look up the object by id. You'll need the SQL modified slightly to return `id` rather than `client_id`):

`client = Clients.objects.raw("select distinct tt.client_id as id ...")`